# Why does emacs (or auctex?) turns -- into "=?

Tags: auctex

When I edit LaTeX documents with emacs I have auctex turned on and when I type TikZ pictures I have to type `--` a lot. However, emacs (or is it auctex?) turns `--` into `"=`. If I add another `-` I finally get the `--` that I wanted. Why is that and how to turn it of?

(It seems pretty darn impossible to search for `--` or `"=` both here or on google…)

(Should this be on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/?)

Comment: Or ask on the auctex mailing list. My quess is it comes from languages that has a lot of hyphenated words, where you'd like to allow hyphenation in the two parts of the word. But I agree it is really annoying when dealing with tikz and I'd also like to know how to disable it in certain envs.

Comment: Are you loading `bibtex` package with `bulgarian` option in your document?

Comment: Nope, it also happens in documents without bibliography and with no `bibtex` package loaded. It happens in my German documents.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `babel`, not `bibtex`.  Ok, also German is fine.  I'll provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some languages, AUCTeX provides support for hyphenation and quoting for many languages, see https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files-for-Different-Languages  Sometimes, people may not like the default behavior, but it can be easily adjusted by setting the appropriate variables.  In your case, you have to look at [`LaTeX-babel-hyphen-language-alist`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-LaTeX_002dbabel_002dhyphen_002dlanguage_002dalist)

> *User Option*: **LaTeX-babel-hyphen-language-alist**
>
> Used for overriding the behavior of hyphen insertion for specific languages. Every element in this alist is a list of three items. The first item should specify the affected language as a string. The second item denotes the hyphen string to be used as a string. The third item, a boolean, controls the behavior of hyphen insertion and should be non-nil if the special hyphen should be inserted after inserting a literal ‘`-`’ character, i.e. on second key press.

In order to enable this feature, AUCTeX look at the options passed to the  `babel` package.  So, assuming you're loading `babel` with `german` language option, add the following line to your Emacs init file and restart Emacs:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-babel-hyphen-language-alist '(("german" "" nil)))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! (Although I use `ngerman` and hence use `(setq LaTeX-babel-hyphen-language-alist '(("ngerman" "" nil)))`.)